# scan A4 doc > pdf > ocr > translate to english?

Tags: pdf, language, ocr, translation, scanning

I've tried using a combination of

- my home scanner to create a '300 dpi', 'document', 'pdf' (options on Canon all-in-one)
- ZoHoViewer to create either an RTF or TXT file
- google docs to translate

I'm not sure how good or bad a product ZoHoViewer is, but the following:

*Als Arbeitsmarkbehörde haben wir den gesetzlichen Auftrag, die Vermittelbarkeit von*

turns into:

*AlsArbeitsmarktbeh6rde      habenwirdengesetzlichenAuftrag,dieVermittelbarkeit     vonSt...*

consequently, goog docs makes a pig's breakfast of trying to translate it.

Does anyone have any better suggestions (preferably free online services)

Comment: Since there isn't an "exact" duplicate, I'm leaving this one open. However you should go through the questions I linked, since they will probably offer possible solutions

Comment: In case anyone's interested the translation should be "When labor market authority, we have a statutory mandate, the employability of" - or something along those lines

Comment: correction: "As the labour market authority" ... sounds better :)

Comment: @Molly - It was just a copy 'n' paste into Google Translate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% perfect but the best out of all the things I have tried:

http://www.paperfile.net/ combined with a language pack (free to download instructions in app) copy and paste whole of the text to a google doc, then use the tools > translate in google docs

Answer (score 5):

There have been several other questions on SuperUser on OCR, which might be worth checking out for possible solutions.

Most notably [this answer by Molly looks promising:](https://superuser.com/questions/68459/which-ocr-software-has-the-most-options/79093#79093)

> I really like **[TopOCR](http://www.topocr.com/)**,
>   certainly a great addition to your
>   scan tools:
>
> - Incredible OCR accuracy, upto 99.8% with a 3 MP camera
> - No page limits, and no extra downloads or components needed
> - Handles images with mixed text and graphics (Manual or Auto Zoning)
> - Tolerates skew and uneven lighting
> - Multiple text output formats, including searchable PDF and HTML
> - Able to read 11 different languages
> - Powerful, easy to use Image Processing with Image Dewarping
> - Supports Smartphones: See some Smartphone samples
> - Includes built-in, full featured Text and Image WYSIWYG Editors
> - Post-processing spell checker for all 11 languages
> - Built-in Text-To-Speech software. How about OCR to MP3?
> - Includes a built-in multi-lingual text translater
> - Supports a Command Line Interface and a GUI
> - Make a high performance document Search and Indexing system
> - Browser Helper Mode supports creating free audio eBooks
> - With TopOCR's Web Engine it's easy to add new features
>
> [image]
>
> it's very accurate and works excellent
>   with low quality images such as
>   photographs of pages/documents
>
> *TopOCR is freeware (can be made portable with [Universal
>   Extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract))*

Further reading:

[Which OCR software has the most options?](https://superuser.com/questions/68459/which-ocr-software-has-the-most-options)

[Practical OCR solution for converting a large book to a digital format?](https://superuser.com/questions/41620/practical-ocr-solution-for-converting-a-large-book-to-a-digital-format)

[How to extract text with OCR from a PDF on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/28426/how-to-extract-text-with-ocr-from-a-pdf-on-linux)

Comment: this "downvoting business" here is getting ridiculous, in fact TopOCR is ideal for this this job as it 'understands' German (and a lot of other languages) and includes a translator. +1 and flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: 2 Up, 2 down :/

Comment: Looks nice, but I don't really want to have to pull my camera out when I want to scan a doc. I can see how that might be nice if you do not have a scanner or are out and about with your phone though.

Comment: It means you can also do it on scanned document ;-)

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.

Comment: I tried topOCR with another doc and it is useless. Tildas and stuff all over the place [this was from a doc scanned at 600dpi]. Also I am undergoing the pain of switching from windows to mac and topocr is windows only.

Answer (score 4):

Given that the OCR has converted:

> Als Arbeitsmarkbehörde ...

to:

> AlsArbeitsmarktbeh6rde ...

A couple of things spring to mind.

1. Try scanning at a higher dpi. It looks like it can't recognise the space between the words, a higher dpi *might* improve that.
2. Can you set the language of your OCR program? I see that it's converted the "ö" to a "6". While this might be a problem caused by the resolution it might also be that as "ö" isn't an everyday part of English, the program is choosing the "next best" fit - in this case "6".

Comment: Good points Chris!

Comment: Have rescanned at 600dpi, am just waiting (forever) for zamzar to send me the converted doc....I guess when it's free you cannot expect too much, but nearly a day!? Too long

Comment: Now I just checked and it the conversion expired. Starting again. Harumph.

Comment: Naah. zamzar is useless at recognising spaces even at 600 dpi, will try another tool for conversion.