# How to do OCR on a PDF document?

Tags: pdf, ocr, english, hebrew

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract text with OCR from a PDF on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/28426/how-to-extract-text-with-ocr-from-a-pdf-on-linux)

I have a few documents in English and Hebrew that I scanned in and converted to PDF format.

Is there some free or cheap utility that can process a scanned PDF and do OCR, at least in English, preferably also in Hebrew?

Thanks!

Comment: A couple of similar questions.  http://superuser.com/questions/28426/how-to-extract-text-with-ocr-from-a-pdf-on-linux/33203#33203 http://superuser.com/questions/64124/extracting-text-from-a-pdf-scanned-book http://superuser.com/questions/97470/scan-a4-doc-pdf-ocr-translate-to-english

Comment: The author of this question did not specify that he is running Linux.  The so-called possible duplicate question is too localized, and may not apply at all to the author of this question.

Comment: @eleven81 - Correct, I was asking for Windows.

Comment: Not only this is not duplicate - it's still unanswered. All 3 answers only yields into text extracts and not a PDF text-selectable document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a list](http://www.freeocr.net/) of free OCR software for Windows.

1. [FreeOCR](http://www.paperfile.net/)
2. [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)
3. [WeOcr Tesseract Web Interface](http://asv.aso.ecei.tohoku.ac.jp/tesseract/)
4. [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/)
5. [Windows GUI for GOCR](http://www.brothersoft.com/utilities/scanner_and_ocr/gocr_windows_frontend_38579.html)
6. [OCR Desktop](http://www.ocrtools.com/fi/prdOCRFree.aspx)
7. [Simple OCR](http://www.simpleocr.com/Download.asp)
8. [TopOCR](http://www.topocr.com/download.html)

However, these programs need an image input, not a PDF input.  For this, try a [PDF-to-JPG converter](http://www.pdf-to-jpg.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I found an [interesting idea](http://www.labnol.org/software/convert-scanned-pdf-images-to-text-with-google-ocr/5158/) that lets Google do all the work of OCR'ing the PDF files for you.

Comment: Rather than what's at that link, it's simpler now to just use http://docs.google.com/viewer now.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use [Ghostview](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) to convert them to an image, then [Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) to convert them to text. This is a totally free, open source, cross platform solution that I have had very good results with when trying to convert plain text. I don't use it for complex documents with tables and such, but for plain text you can't beat the price.