# How to ocr pdf documents in osx

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, software-rec, ocr

Is there any software that comes with OSX or can be downloaded to do OCR on a PDF document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat "meta" answer, but I'll post it anyway since you haven't got many other answers. See:

- [How to extract text with OCR from a PDF on Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/28426/how-to-extract-text-with-ocr-from-a-pdf-on-linux) — some of the answers work on OSX as well
- [How to do OCR on a PDF document?](https://superuser.com/questions/109628/how-to-do-ocr-on-a-pdf-document) — closed as duplicate of the above, but still has good, useful (and different) answers. (Another reason not to delete closed questions, but to keep/merge them.)
- Or use **[Google viewer](http://docs.google.com/viewer)**

Or see some of the questions on the right under "related questions". I went through several of them carefully, but none stood out as particularly useful: but you may find something.

Answer (score 2):

you can use OmniPage it's about 500$.

- [OmniPage Pro X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00005US8L)

also you can use this software for your job:

- [ABBYY FInder Reader](http://www.abbyyusa.com/finereader/?_kk=ABBYY%20fine%20reader&_kt=2cb34634-e3b1-44b3-907e-08a40559e634&gclid=CMC94L_R2qMCFQo5gwodkm-h7Q)
- [Readiris](http://www.irislink.com/c2-1584-189/Readiris-12---OCR-Software-------Convert-your-Paper-Documents-into-Editable-Text-.aspx)